# The Google Data Calendar Resource API is now deprecated and is scheduled for sunset in January 2017

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

Currently we use Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Client Library 1.9.0.1190 for by-directional synchronization of data between google calendar and  our custom application using OAuth2 Web credentials. Is there any change expected to this?

> The Google Data Calendar Resource API is now deprecated and is scheduled for sunset in January 2017. Apps should instead use the Directory API's Calendar Resource object.

Bit confused between these "Directory API's Calendar Resource object", 
"Google Data Calendar Resource API" and "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no need for you to worry. The deprecation notice was directed towards Admin SDK domain users who uses Google Data Calendar Resource API which is based on the [old Google Data APIs](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/developers-guide).

You, on the other hand, are using the up-to-date [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview) which is availabe through REST calls or [client-specific libraries](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/downloads). So unless you are a domain user who uses the Admin SDK, this should be the least of your problems.

Comment: Noted. Thank you so much for confirming.